# RegEx to match pair of Rectangular Brackets using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Can someone help me with a Javascript regular expression?  I need to match pairs of brackets. For example, it should match "[abc123]", "[123abc]" in the following string:

"this is a test [abc123]], another test [[123abc]. This is an left alone closing"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about the string `"... [foo [bar] baz] ..."`?

Comment: The Text will only contain patters like [abc123], there will be no such patter as you have commented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't require nested brackets,

```
// theString = "this is a test [abc123]], another test [[123abc]. 
// This is an left alone closing";
return theString.match(/\[[^\[\]]*\]/g);
// returns ["[abc123]", "[123abc]"]
```

to extract the contents, see the following example:

```
var rx = /\[([^\[\]]*)\]/g;
var m, a = [];
while((m = rx.exec(theString)))      
  a.push(m[1]);
return a;
```

Comment: OMG, your avatar is [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f612/index.htm) 